# I am unable to understand the following code can anyone please clear up this to me?

Tags: solidity

Particularly the usage of keccak256 and the return statement used here.

```
function isTokenTransferOK(address currentOwner, address newOwner)
    public
    pure
    returns (bool ok)
{
    // Check an arbitrary condition to see if transfer should proceed
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(currentOwner, newOwner))[0] == 0x7f;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`abi.encodePacked()` essentially concatenates data. So the call here forms a sequence of 40 bytes, where the first 20 bytes are the address `currentOwner` and the second 20 bytes are the address `newOwner`.

`keccak256()` is a hashing function very similar to SHA3. It's used to calculate a hash of the output of `abi.encodePacked()`.

`[0]` retrieves the first element of an array. In this case, it's the first byte of the hash calculated above.

`== 0x7f` is `true` if and only if that byte is the hexadecimal value `0x7f`.

So the function hashes the current and new owner addresses and returns `true` if the first byte of that hash is `0x7f`. Otherwise it returns `false`.